# Using astype() to convert string to number

Tags: python, pandas

For the following simple dataframe

```
data = {'Name':['ww', 'xx'],
        'v1':[19968,5.83],
        'v2':[39936,11.31],
        'v3':[79872,19.26]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

where `df` looks like

```
  Name        v1        v2        v3
0   ww  19968.00  39936.00  79872.00
1   xx      5.83     11.31     19.26
```

when I use `x = df.iloc[1,:].astype(float)`, I get this error

```
could not convert string to float: 'xx'
```

I expect to convert the row 1 to have: `x = [5.83 11.31 19.26]`

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you mean `df.iloc[:,1].astype(float)`?

Comment: No. I want to read x=[5.83     11.31     19.26].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sliced the rows here and took all columns (thus the error as the first column contains strings).

You should rather slice both the rows **and** columns (to get rid of the first):

```py
df.iloc[1,1:].astype(float)
```

or, explicitly select the number-only columns:

```py
df.select_dtypes('number').iloc[1].astype(float)
```

Output:

```
v1     5.83
v2    11.31
v3    19.26
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```